# Model looking different in blender & maya

Tags: modeling, texturing

[image]
[image]

The first image is rendered in Maya,

And the second is from Blender Cycles.

Both of them are the same OBJ file imported.

I have two questions :

**1. They are the same exact OBJ files but Blender imported version lacks subdivision, eg around the apple logo. If I do subdivide the mesh around it, it gets better. Why is this happening and how I can I prevent this in the future?**

**2. Why are the textures that show on Maya not loading on Blender? Are they not compatible? If so, what method would you recommend to import exactly like the first image?**

Thank you all as always !

Below is the blender version with more subdiv around apple logo.

[image]

Here's a link to the download.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VQgvtY1VR9G3GzzHsXY9szgyYLfUIq1b?usp=sharing

Comment: In the first image you can clearly see that *a light was added to the scene*. If you read about obj files: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file you'll see that **.obj neither supports lights nor complex glossy plastic shaders** (to exactly match a product by apple) and even in maya you would have to add the subdivisions as well... Also please only ask one question per post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: But then why does my model look glossy and doesnt lack subdiv in Maya when I import it? Literally its as it is in the first image when I opened it

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to upload the folder.https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VQgvtY1VR9G3GzzHsXY9szgyYLfUIq1b?usp=sharing

Comment: Anyone interested its VP_Free_Iphone_OBJ.obj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Are you using any secret, non-public or [industrial light and magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_Light_%26_Magic) in-house version of Maya?*

---

#### CG 101

**Materials** and **Lights** are **unique per render engine** and cannot be transferred over easily. Even in 2021, manual tweaking is required to match lights and shaders of different engines since there is still no unified way of *describing* a shader or lights. [MaterialX](https://www.materialx.org/) is quite promising though.

---

#### How it really looks like in Blender and Maya

Importing the provided `obj` file into *Maya 2019* and starting the render leads into a black screen because there are no lights in the scene (warning). When importing the `obj` into *Blender* and switching the *Workspace* to *Shading* on the other hand, gets us a good looking preview instantly:

[image]
*Note: 'Alpha Blend' is enabled for the glass material (requirement for glass in eevee).*

---

#### Wavefront obj

In the first image you provided, you can clearly see that a light was added to the scene. If you read about `obj` files: **https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file**, you'll see that `obj` is a pretty old *geometry* file format and neither supports lights nor modern *complex glossy plastic shaders* in order to exactly match a product by apple:

> OBJ (or .OBJ) is a geometry definition file format ...
> although still widely used, is outdated and does not fully support later technologies such as specular maps and parallax maps.

**However, both DCCs trying to get the most out of the obj file in order to full-fill modern requirements** (like the principled shader).

Related: **[.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541)**

---

#### Subdivisions

Adding *subdivisions* is not nessessary, the geometry is already pretty bad and messed up. I guess the author applied the subdivision before publishing the model to cover up any mistakes:

[image]
*IMHO the geometry is not intended for any close-up shot of the apple logo. Also Maya's viewport is based on a specular model so glossiness is all over the place.*

Further reading: [**topologyguides.com**](https://topologyguides.com/artifacts)

Comment: I am using Maya 2020 and I only added lights to the first image provided, and in Blender I do get the textures like the image on screen and wooden textures but still dont understand why theres a difference when I import to different programs

Comment: **CG 101**: lights and materials are unique per render engine and can't transferred over to another package. Read my answer carefully and try to understand what obj is capable of @CONQUERERHOON

Comment: Much appreciate your details :) I checked the download source it does say it is for 3DS Max and I guess it just worked for Maya since its also Autodesk program and maybe compatible

Comment: Also in Maya/Max you'd have to tweak the shaders and add some lights to get a realistic looking Iphone. Since this is a geometry format as mentioned it's not made for any tool.